# How to apply existing functions to new class?

Tags: clojure

In my project many clients will modify a map in server. I use a `ref` of `map`, like this:

```
(def dict (ref {})) ; the map we play with
```

And I update this map using `dosync`, the STM way. But I found it not as fast as I wish:

```
user=> (time (dotimes [n 1000000] (dosync ( alter xx assoc xx 1 1))))
"Elapsed time: 2470.766 msecs"
```

So I decide to use native Java CuncurrentHashMap to take the place of Clojure build-in map and STM. How can I wrap Java CuncurrentHashMap into Clojure so that i can modify it like Clojure map, using assoc, contains?, dissoc and so on. This will make me modify lest line of code.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `atom`, as you are only modifying a single value you don't need a transaction and hence no need for `ref`

```
user=> (def dict (atom {}))
user=> (time (dotimes [n 1000000] (swap! dict assoc :xx 1)))
"Elapsed time: 108.105703 msecs"
```